# Is it possible to have boolean expressions in the select-clause in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

In mysql you can do `select name <> '' from persons where person_id = 1000` and it will return a 1 or zero, is there a way to do something similar in Firebird with DML? Based on what I've been able to determine I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firebird 3 and later this is possible, as the introduction of the `BOOLEAN` data type now allows this type of expression in the select clause. Such a boolean expression will return true/false, although some tools might map that to 1/0 for you.

In Firebird 2.5 and earlier you will have to map this yourself, for example using [`CASE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case):

```sql
select case when name <> '' then 1 else 0 end from atable where person_id = 1000
```

or [`IIF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-iif):

```sql
select iif(name <> '', 1, 0) from atable where person_id = 1000
```

This also works in Firebird 3 and higher.

Comment: I got 'token unknown - where' using both of these methods.  Using FB2.5.

Comment: @user1455270 Sorry, I forgot the `from`-clause, which is required in Firebird, as I literally copied the query from your question and only modified the expression.